# How to setup HyperLedger Fabric on production

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

In every tutorial I see on web is about setting up development environment for the HyperLedger fabric. I know that.

Now I want to setup a Hyper Ledger Fabric runtime/environment on server where I want to deploy my network.

How do I setup the HyperLedger Fabric for Live clients on server? Can I use the **fabric-dev-servers** scripts?

Answer (score 1):

Below is a little thought for deploying Hyperledger fabric apps in production.

Since all the Hyperledger fabric roles are deployed by docker, we should put container orchestration in higher priority, over clients and servers.

Use a more mature method to deploy your fabric network instead of simply starting up your fabric network with a single node. There exist a plenty of open-source container orchestration tools, which help companies to deploy their servers in production. For example, using Kubernetes or Docker swarm to deploy fabric network can help you load balance your apps and improve the overall performance of applications.

External database is needed for storage of some specific data. Hyperledger fabric uses Couchdb for blockchain database. You cannot invoke and generate all your data on blockchain. Moreover, especially some identifier key, like timestamp, cannot be used as main key in Hyperledger fabric network, since this is distributed system and peers execute chaincode at different times. Therefore,things will be different than a simple deployment on a normal server.

Diving into deployment in production environment, there are many details that we need to handle carefully. Using Message Queue for connection and decoupling, monitoring blockchain transaction for knowing the runtime status and tracing error, etc.

However, I still cannot elaborately discuss how we set our production environment with just a simple question and answer. We should share more information and use our own thoughts.